# How to integrate Heroku with Google Cloud SQL (native - GCP) in Nestjs/Typeorm?

Tags: heroku, nestjs, google-cloud-sql, typeorm, nestjs-config

I'm currently really frustating cause cannot deploy my app to Heroku and connect my db to Google Cloud SQL.

What am I already did?

- I have been set up SSL to connect them
- I have been set up Cloud SQL Auth Proxy (+ set up Cloud SQL CLient role in IAM Manager)
- I have been did buildpacks via Heroku approaches
  etc.

And overall failed.

This is my config database via Typeorm in Nestjs.

```typescript
    import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm"
    const fs = require("fs");
    require('dotenv').config()

    export class OrmConfig {
        // Config TypeOrm
        getConfig() {
             const ormConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
                 type: 'postgres',
                 url: 'postgres://myusername:mypassword@myhostincloudsql(publicip):5432/mydb',
                 // host: 'myhostincloudsql(public ip)',
                 // port: 5432,
                 // username: 'myusername',
                 // password: 'mypassword',
                 // database: 'mydb',
                 entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.js,.ts}'],
                 synchronize: false,
                 migrationsRun: true,
                 logging: false,
                 logger: 'file',
                 migrations: [
                     'dist/database/migrations/**/*{.js, .ts}'
                 ],
                 cli: {
                     migrationsDir: 'database/migrations'
                 },
                 ssl: true,
                 extra: {
                      ssl: {
                           ca: fs.readFileSync('./src/config/server-ca.pem'),
                           cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/config/client-cert.pem'),
                           key: fs.readFileSync('./src/config/client-key.pem'),
                           // rejectUnauthorized: false
                      }
                 }
            }

            return ormConfig
        }
    }

    export default new OrmConfig().getConfig()
```

This is my `app.module.ts`

```typescript
    import { SendGridModule } from '@anchan828/nest-sendgrid';
    import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    // import { BlogModule } from './blog/blog.module';
    import OrmConfig from './config/ormConfig';
    import { BusinessContactModule } from './contact/business/business.module';
    import { InvestorNotificationController } from './contact/investor/investment-recommendation/investor-notification.controller';
    import { InvestmentRecommendationModule } from './contact/investor/investment-recommendation/investor-notification.module';
    import { InvestorContactModule } from './contact/investor/angel-investor/investor.module';
    import { EmitenCampaignModule } from './emiten-campaign/emiten-campaign.module';
    import { EmitenModule } from './emiten/emiten.module';
    import { FlashMobileModule } from './flash-mobile/flash-mobile.module';
    import { CoreModule } from './global/core.module';
    import { Agent } from './middleware/agent';
    import { AuthModule } from './middleware/auth.module';
    import { TekenajaModule } from './tekenaja/tekenaja.module';
    import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
    require('dotenv').config();

    @Module({
       imports: [
         /**
         * ================================
         * Typeorm Config
         * ================================
         */
         SendGridModule.forRoot({
           apikey: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
         }),
         TypeOrmModule.forRoot(OrmConfig), // This is I call it
         ConfigModule.forRoot(),
         AuthModule,
         TekenajaModule,
         FlashMobileModule,
         CoreModule,
         EmitenModule,
         EmitenCampaignModule,
         // InvestorContactModule,
         // BusinessContactModule,
         UserModule,
         // BlogModule
         InvestmentRecommendationModule
       ]
     })
     export class AppModule implements NestModule { 
       configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
         consumer
         .apply(Agent)
         .forRoutes('/');
       }
     }
```

NB: Anyway, I'm using public ip in Google Cloud SQL

I have tried connect it from Heroku Postgres, and works. And I try with Cloud SQL fields, getting error something like this

[image: Error response]

Now, what should I do in order to connected between them? I hope reply my issue guys. Many thanks.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue. As mentioned @Sebastian Pietrzak, I should implemented `0.0.0.0/0` in Authorized Network in the Connection Menu. And for the additional you have to set the SSL appoach.

[image]

Many thanks everyones

Comment: This one works perfectly to me

Answer (score 1):

Try running the Cloud SQL Proxy in addition to your app in the same dynamo.

For example:

```
web: trap '' SIGTERM; ./cloud_sql_proxy -credential_file sa.json -instances=INSTANCE_CONN_NAME=tcp:5432 & npm start & wait -n; kill -SIGTERM -$$; wait
```

Note, you'll need to ensure the Cloud SQL Proxy binary and a credential file is included with your app. And you won't want to check those into source control.

See https://help.heroku.com/CTFS2TJK/how-do-i-run-multiple-processes-on-a-dyno.

Comment: Does it safe for production?

Comment: I can't speak to best practices on Heroku, but the Cloud SQL Proxy is definitely production quality.

Comment: I'll try it. `web: trap '' SIGTERM; puma -C config/puma.rb & sidekiq & wait -n; kill -SIGTERM -$$; wait` can I add `&& npm start` or not?

Comment: bash: sidekiq: command not found
bash: puma: command not found
any idea for the link? cannot be used for the command

Comment: You'll need to include a credentials file in there too. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/48#issuecomment-1012844535 for details.

Comment: Updated my comment to make the start command more clear. The example from the link above is for Ruby users and so you won't be using puna or sidekiq.

Comment: I have added the command in Procfile, still same

Answer (score 0):

In CloudSQL - your instance must have Public IP address ( section Connection ) and you need address IP in Authorised network from where you will try connect. Ofc you can setup 0.0.0.0 but don't do it. Better way is setup ssh connection.

[image: Public Adress]

Comment: I have been did it, but still didn't work. The result in heroku logs still same like image above. Did you know how to get the ip from heroku app? I'm currently using quotaguard to get static ip, but still no effect

Comment: Heroku use dynamic IP. you need set 0.0.0.0 in autorised network.
I checked with Heroku and its works.

Comment: I already set the ip. Still getting error


2022-01-15T06:26:43.855533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 120 seconds of launch
2022-01-15T06:26:43.928593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-01-15T06:26:44.018963+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-01-15T06:26:44.251980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2022-01-15T06:26:44.341858+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed